# Is this query possible in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
ID A B C
0  x   x
1  x
2  x x
3    x
```

I would like to obtain this with a query (SQLite syntax if possible)

```
A 3
B 2
C 1
```

I've been using CASE WHEN clause, like this

```
WITH solutions AS (SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN `B` = 'x' THEN 'A'
        WHEN `B` = 'x' THEN 'B'
        WHEN `C` = 'x' THEN 'C'
    END AS 'Solution'
FROM use_cases)
SELECT solution, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM solutions
GROUP BY Solution ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

But it won't work in case a row present more than one column with 'x',  as the WHEN evaluation will stop at the first case is found.

Comment: You will need to "Unpivot" With `UNION [ALL]` first..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select col, count(*)
from (select 'A' as col from t where A = 'x' union all
      select 'B' from t where B = 'x' union all
      select 'C' from t where C = 'x' 
     ) x
group by col
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need UNION ALL:

```
select 'A' col1, count(A = 'x') col2 from tablename 
union all 
select 'B', count(B = 'x') from tablename 
union all
select 'C', count(C = 'x') from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hCkvbhsYSmf9MWmaTFeR1z/1).
Or with a `CTE` to avoid multiple scans of the table:

```
with cte as (
  select count(A = 'x') cola, count(B = 'x') colb, count(C = 'x') colc
  from tablename
)  
select 'A' col1, cola col2 from cte 
union all 
select 'B', colb from cte
union all
select 'C', colc from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hCkvbhsYSmf9MWmaTFeR1z/2).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| A    | 3    |
| B    | 2    |
| C    | 1    |
```

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate which DB your solution would work in. The OP asked for SQLite 'if possible' so I'm not saying your solution is invalid but your proposed solution may not work as expected in SQLite. In SQLite, count(A = 'x') will give the same answer as count(A = 'y'). In your case you may have gotten the correct answer because your data contained NULLs where it didn't contain an X. The only thing you were counting, at least in SQLite, were non-null values. (A = 'x') returns FALSE which is 0 and count() counts non-nulls so since FALSE is not null it gets counted.

Comment: Sorry, In the last sentence I meant to say ... (A = 'y') returns FALSE ...

Comment: I've seen the tag of the question and I already provided a fiddle for SQLite, so no need to *indicate which DB my solution would work*. My solution is based on the OP's sample data and requirement. It does count the non nulls and this is the requirement. A = 'x' in count(A = 'x') is just an indicator it could be count(A) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically wanted to check for the X then you could take advantage of the fact that (at least in SQLite) TRUE is equivalent to 1 and FALSE to 0 so something simple like the following would work:

```
SELECT 'A', sum(A = 'x') from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', sum(B = 'x') from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', sum(C = 'x') from MyTable;
```

Another simple solution is to rely on the fact that count() only counts non-null values. So if the columns contain NULL in the places where it doesn't contain an X, then this simple SQL will work in SQLite:

```
SELECT 'A', count(A) from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', count(B) from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', count(C) from MyTable;
```

A slight variant of the above ... If the columns that don't contain X have something in them other than NULL … then just convert that to null. For example if the columns that don't contain an X happen to contain a space then the following would work:

```
SELECT 'A', count(nullif (A, ' ')) from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', count(nullif (B, ' ')) from MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', count(nullif (C, ' ')) from MyTable;
```

Note: My proposed approaches will likely require multiple scans of the table but with proper indexing such a penalty could be mitigated. It is possible that CTE-based solutions may be more efficient but you would have to test both approaches to be sure. CTE-based solutions may involve the creation of temp tables (or temp result sets) from potentially multiple subqueries. All of which can make CTEs less efficient in certain circumstances … but YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  Select val, cnt from ( SELECT 'A' as val,A,count(*) as cnt FROM TABLE 
     GROUP BY A
    UNION 
  SELECT 'B' as val,B,count(*) as cnt FROM TABLE 
    Group by B
   UNION 
   SELECT 'C' as val,C,count(*) as cnt FROM TABLE 
   Group by C))
```

Check below output

[image]

or if you want to exclude empty space count then

```
SELECT VAL,CNT FROM(SELECT 'A' AS VAL,A as col,COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM SAMPLEE GROUP BY A
                         UNION
                         SELECT 'B' AS VAL,B as col,COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM SAMPLEE GROUP BY B
                         UNION
                         SELECT 'C' AS VAL,C as col,COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM SAMPLEE GROUP BY C
                         ) where col !=' ';
```

[image]

Comment: Edited can check now